# Create a new symfony project in an existing new git repository

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

When trying to create a new symfony project in a newly created git repository folder I got the error message Project directory is not empty.

Example

```
symfony new myApplication
```

With error message

```
Project directory myApplication is not empty
```

Does anyone find a workaround or cleaner way to do it else than creating the symfony project in a temporary folder and then copying back to the git repository folder ?